# On desktop Telegram: how can I make fonts bigger? i.e. increase fonts size?

Tags: fonts, telegram

the question above says it all, I think: I'm on Ubuntu, installed Telegram on my desktop and the font are way too small for my tired eyes. Is there a way to increase the size of the fonts specifically in Telegram, without changing all my desktop display settings?
P.S.: please simple suggestions, I'm no tech savant..., and thanks in advance.

Comment: thanks, but that's irrelevant to my question and none of those links answer it and most relate to other issues or situations.

Answer (score 6):

click the 3 lines (the hamburger) in the upper left corner, select settings

scroll down to default interface scale, select desired percentage

it will prompt you to restart the program, select ok

I hope this helps :)

Comment: Glad to hear it!  :)